# Website not working after uploading files via FTP

Tags: php, apache, ftp, permissions

I have a website written in PHP, running on an Apache server. In the past, I make a change to a file, upload it back to the server via FTP, and I see the changes reflected in the browser. Recently, I made changes to many files (I changed all references to 'http://' to '//' because we may be using SSL), and I uploaded the entire site back to the server via FTP, overwriting all changes on the server (I used FileZilla client). Now, when I navigate to my site in the browser, nothing shows up (it is just blank). I tried changing the permissions (first 755 for directories and 644 for files, then 755 for everything, then even 777 for everything), but that didn't work. Is it possible that the upload broke something? I'm trying to figure out whether it was the upload that broke something or if it was the changes that I made to the actual files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the apache error log.

Comment: Check /var/log/apache, you need to provide more information. Could be a number of things.

Comment: I don't see apache in /var/log/. I should point out that I don't have full control over the site other than the actual directories/files that make up the website.

Comment: The only log that occurred around the same time is file doesn't exist /usr/share/phpmyadmin/scripts. Does that help?